# jquery save background-color in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to save a change in background-color in local storage after a button click, but it's not saved when refreshing window. Have I forgotten something?

```
$(".btn-secondmenu").click(function(){
   $(".btn-secondmenu").css('background-color', 'red');
        var status = $(".btn-secondmenu");
        localStorage.setItem(".btn-secondmenu", status);
    });
```

Comment: You also need code to set the background-color based on the local storage, something like `if (localStorage.bgColor) $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', localStorage.bgColor);`. All you're doing right now is setting it, you're never actually using it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the color to variable `status`. Your current code sets `$(".btn-secondmenu")`- jQuery object to the localStorage.

```
$(".btn-secondmenu").css('background-color', localStorage.getItem(".btn-secondmenu"));  
//sets the color from localstorage on Dom ready - getItem().

$(".btn-secondmenu").click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');     //use *this* to set color for current button
    var status = $(".btn-secondmenu").css('background-color');  //assign color value to variable
    localStorage.setItem(".btn-secondmenu", status);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxht3o2g/)**

Answer (score 2):

The value of a `localStorage` item can be anything, but it is converted into a string internally. **Your `status` is being converted into a string, so its actual value is not being stored correctly.**

For example:

```
localStorage.setItem('hi', document.createElement('div'));
localStorage.getItem('hi'); // "[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

In your case:

```
var status = $('.btn-secondmenu');
localStorage.setItem('.btn-secondmenu', status);
localStorage.getItem('.btn-secondmenu'); // "[object Object]"
```

To fix this, you can store the actual color value instead, like so:

```
var btnSecondMenu = $('.btn-secondmenu'); 
btnSecondMenu.click(function () {
   btnSecondMenu.css('background-color', 'red');
   localStorage.setItem('.btn-secondmenu', 'red');
});
```

You can then use that value to set your css background-color when the page loads:

```
var storedBgColor = localStorage.getItem('.btn-secondmenu'); // "red"
if (storedBgColor) {
    $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background-color', storedBgColor);
} else {
    // set default color or do something else if you like
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eo671rwa/2/) is an example using the suggestions above.

Comment: *The value of a localStorage item should be a string* - No, it can be anything. JSON, array, object. And it is being stored. You can check resources tab of developer console.

Comment: You are right, but localStorage handles strings internally. The objects are converted into strings. If you did `localStorage.setItem('hi', {a: 1});`, this would store "[object Object]". But, that's not what you want. What you should do is `localStorage.setItem('hi', JSON.stringify({a: 1});` to make sure you can retrieve it via `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hi'))`. I will update my answer to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply's, more options are working. I'm trying now to switch the colors everytime user clicks on the button, and save background-color in localStorage. I've tried several options, but until now I didn't get it to work. Anyone a solution how to tackle this?

```
if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
        getColour = localStorage.background;
        $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', getColour);
    }

$('.btn-secondmenu').click(function(){
    if(getColour == 'blue'){
        localStorage.removeItem('background');
        $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', 'red');
        localStorage.setItem('background', 'red');
        }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem('background');
        $('.btn-secondmenu').css('background', 'blue');
        localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue');
        }
    });
```